# How to deal with saving two datatypes in firebase for same key?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, user-defined-data-types

I am trying to add last seen feature in my app using firebase. So I am trying to update my user's time stamp(each user has `mTimeStamp` key) value with `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` using `onDisconnect()` method, and if the user comes online I am trying to update the user's `mTimeStamp` with the `ValueEventListener` on the reference `.info/connected`. So in one case the value updated is a `Map<String,String>` (which I have read somewhere that when it is retrieved back from Firebase database comes back as `long` primitive) and in one case it is saved as `boolean`.

```
public class PublicUserProfile {
    private int mAge,mSM;
    private double mPR;
   private Long mTimeStamp;
   private Boolean mIsOnline;
    public PublicUserProfile(){}

    public PublicUserProfile(int mAge, int mSM, double mPR, Long mTimeStamp) {
        Log.e("chimap","chad");
        this.mAge = mAge;
        this.mSM = mSM;
        this.mPR = mPR;
        this.mTimeStamp = mTimeStamp;
    }

    public PublicUserProfile(int mAge, int mSM, double mPR, Boolean mIsOnline) {
        Log.e("idhar aye","4 wale");
        this.mAge = mAge;
        this.mSM = mSM;
        this.mPR = mPR;
        this.mIsOnline = mIsOnline;
    }

    public PublicUserProfile(int mAge, int mSM, double mPR) {
        Log.e("idhar aye","3 wale");
        this.mAge = mAge;
        this.mSM = mSM;
        this.mPR = mPR;
    }

    public int getmAge() {
        return mAge;
    }


    public int getmSM() {
        return mSM;
    }


    public double getmPR() {
        return mPR;
    }

    public Long getmTimeStamp() {
        return mTimeStamp;
    }

    public Boolean getmIsOnline() {
        return mIsOnline;
    }
          }
```

Now I am trying to retrieve the data back from firebase using `DataSnapshot.getValue(<T> class)` method, now as `mTimeStamp` can only be saved as either long or as boolean in `PublicUserProfile` class I am getting `DatabaseException` error that class `java.lang.Long` cannot be converted to `myPackagename.PublicUserProfile`.

To counter this error I created an extra field in `PublicUserProfile` `mIsOnline`so that the second constructor is called if the value is `Boolean` instead of `Long` but again I was getting the same `DatabaseException` error that `java.lang.Long` object can not be converted to `PublicUserProfile` even though at the same time I was looking in my database 'mTimeStamp' was set to `true` but I feel this error is reasonable because both in database and model class the name of key and field name should be same respectively. Also this approach has a problem because even if I try to save two keys in database i.e. one for `long`(to save timestamp(`mTimeStamp`)) and one for `boolean` (to save weather person is online or not(`mIsOnline`)) because  when I call `onDisconnect()` method I can only do one operation i.e. either remove `mIsOnline` or `setValue` to `mTimeStamp` in database.

There is one more problem related to saving two keys i.e I want to retrieve 10 `PublicUserProfile`s and I want to show them in a `RecyclerView` in an order such that online people are shown first and then recent offline users and Firebase offers only one `orderByValue()` method so I can use only one key either `mTimeStamp` or `mIsOnline`.

How should I make my `PublicUserProfile` or how should I make calls to the database to add presence system in my app?

Comment: AFAIK I know Firebase uses setters to set the values. BTW I suspect you are doing `DataSnapshot.getValue(PublicUserProfile.class)` for a `Long` may be `mTimeStamp`.

Comment: Yes I am doing `DataSnapshot.getValue(PublicUserProfile.class)` but sometimes `mTimeStamp` is `Long` and sometimes `Boolean`

Comment: Your model is not good. You should save one type of value. Also `DataSnapshot.getValue(PublicUserProfile.class)` will never work instead `DataSnapshot.getValue(Long.class)` will work in the cases `mTimeStamp` is `Long`.

Comment: @BirendraSingh Then what will I do if `mTimeStamp` is boolean, I can't change the data type of `mTimeStamp` in my model class dynamically. It can either be `Long` or `Boolean`.

Comment: Use `try-catch`.

Comment: @BirendraSingh Even though I use `try-catch` when I will use `DataSnapshot.getValue(PublicUserProfile.class)` it will try assigning `mTimeStamp` in model class to `Boolean` or `Long` depending upon the data type saved in database because if you use Model class to retrieve data from firebase the names of fields in Model class and the names of keys in database should match. So it will not use `mIsOnline` in model class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154521/discussion-between-birendra-singh-and-kartik-watwani).